# How to programmatically update the variable to match the iteration

Tags: java, android

I have the following for-each loop:

```
for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String message = data.getKey().toString();
    textview.setText(message);
}
```

Now there are different textviews with ids `textview1` `textview2` `textview3`..etc (can grow and shrink). How do I do that in the for-each loop though? Using some counter and somehow concat it to the variable?
I want the different messages to display in the different textviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify your code like this:

```
int i = 1;
for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("textview" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(id);
    String message = data.getKey().toString();
    textview.setText(message);
    i++;
}
```

with `getResources().getIdentifier("textview" + i, "id", getPackageName());` you find the integer id of a `View` by using its name id. 
You may have to supply a `Context` to `getResources()` like:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("textview" + i, "id", context.getPackageName());
```

if this code is not inside an activity.

Comment: I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: This means that there is no TextView named textview1!

Comment: You guys are awesome! I really named them `tv1`, `tv2` instead, my bad! It works!